# Delay after each CSS translateX animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm using CSS transform translateX to move a Gif from left to right. The gif stops and belches towards the end of the Gif animation but the Gif is still being translated along the X co-ordinate, so it doesn't look good!

How can I add a pause/delay at the end of the translateX.

There's a similar question on Stackoverflow regarding a Rotate, and the answer is the following code:

```
 66%, 100% {
  transform:rotatey(0deg);
}
```

But for the life of me I can't figure out how to apply to mine.

```css
.gif-image {
 width: 30%;
  animation-name: slideLeftToRight;
  animation-duration: 20s; 
  animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
}

@keyframes slideLeftToRight {
  from {transform: translateX(0px)} 
  to {transform: translateX(400px)}
}




body{
 background-color: #6dba94;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img class="gif-image" src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/672882/screenshots/1972683/character-rig-800x600.gif" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting one since you can't use a transition delay quite the same as in most circumstances since the GIF never stops. So your case basically boils down to timing up the animation to match with the GIF timing. This is going to be hard to do, especially if you didn't make the GIF yourself. (If you did, maybe it'd be easier for you to tell exactly when the guy starts and stops walking, in milliseconds.)

That said, hard does not mean impossible.

**Important note before we start:** The GIF is gonna keep playing over and over, even if you update your code in JS Fiddle or CodePen or a Stack Snippet or what have you. So you can end up thinking your animation timing is all off when it's actually not. In testing this, I copied the URL I was working from in CodePen and then kept closing the tab, reopening a new one, and pasting the URL into there to reload it with the GIF starting from its beginning. This is tedious, but I don't know a better way.

Anyway...

First you gotta figure out how long the GIF lasts because it'll make our life a million times easier to base the animation duration around the GIF's duration. I was guessing initially that it'd be a nice round number like exactly 5 seconds, but in testing it seemed to get off after a few iterations, like it was actually slightly longer. I'm ballparking it at 5.15 seconds.

So let's make our guy walk to the right when he's done belching. First we gotta figure out how long exactly he takes before he starts walking. (If you know this number exactly, your life will be way easier. I had to use guess and check.)

With some testing, I figured out he starts walking approximately 42% of the way into the GIF, or about 2163ms into it, if the GIF is 5.15 seconds long (5150ms). So we don't start our translation until that point:

```
@keyframes animationName {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  42% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(200px);
  }
}
```

That basically gives us this:

```css
.gif-image {
 width: 250px;
 animation-iteration-count: infinite;
 animation-name: slideLeftToRightRepeating;
  animation-duration: 5.15s;
}
@keyframes slideLeftToRightRepeating {
 0% {
  transform: translateX(0px);
 }
 42% {
  transform: translateX(0px);
 }
 100% {
  transform: translateX(200px);
 }
}
body {
 background-color: #6dba94;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div><img class="gif-image" src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/672882/screenshots/1972683/character-rig-800x600.gif" /></div>
</div>
```

Once we get that part down, if you want him to keep walking sideways like you have in your question with a long animation duration, it's just a matter of multiplying our animation duration by however many times you want to repeat the motion, and then dividing our percentages by that same amount.

So let's say you want to have him repeat the animation five times. Our animation duration now becomes (5 * 5.15s) = 20.75s.

Then, in our percentages, every 20% of the animation (because we're dividing it in fifths) will be a repeat of the pattern we established above. So at the 20% mark, we have the same effect as at the 100% mark above.

We figured out he starts walking around 42% of the way through, so we take 42% of 20% to get 8.4%. Our keyframes now look like this:

```
@keyframes animationName {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  8.4% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateX(200px);
  }
  28.4% {
    transform: translateX(200px);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translateX(400px);
  }
  .....
}
```

In practice, this proved to be not quite right (I guess my 42% estimation isn't perfect). Revising our numbers a bit, I came up with 0%, 11.5%, 20%, 31.5%, etc.

At the end, we have `100% { transform: translateX(1000px); }`. That's a 200px translation five times.

Here's a pretty good starting spot where things go decently well, but the timing isn't exact. I'll leave it up to you to mess with it to get the numbers exactly right and also to adjust the distance he walks each time to fit your circumstance. Hopefully this helps.

Note that I think your life will be easier if you set the width of the GIF as well as the translation distance in fixed units, otherwise you may find that with relative units like percentages that your guy appears to either be walking in place or taking huge bounds across the screen depending how wide it is.

```css
.gif-image {
  width: 250px;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 20.75s;
  animation-name: slideLeftToRightSlowly;
}

@keyframes slideLeftToRightRepeating {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0x);
  }
  42% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(200px);
  }
}

@keyframes slideLeftToRightSlowly {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  11.5% {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  20% {
    transform: translateX(200px);
  }
  31.5% {
    transform: translateX(200px);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translateX(400px);
  }
  51.5% {
    transform: translateX(400px);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateX(600px);
  }
  71.5% {
    transform: translateX(600px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(800px);
  }
  91.5% {
    transform: translateX(800px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(1000px);
  }
}

body {
  background-color: #6dba94;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div><img class="gif-image" src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/672882/screenshots/1972683/character-rig-800x600.gif" /></div>
</div>
```